# pandas reshape tuples - cannot reindex form duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

For a pandas dataframe of:

[image]

defined by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 're_foo':[1,2,3], 're_bar':[4,5,6], 're_foo_baz':[0.4, 0.8, .9], 're_bar_baz':[.4,.5,.6], 'iteration':[1,2,3]})
display(df)
```

I want to reshape to the following format:

```
id, metric_kind, foo      , bar      , iteration
1, regular     , 1        , 4        , 1
1, baz         , 0.4    , 0.4        , 1
...
```

From [pandas reshape multiple columns fails with KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376909/pandas-reshape-multiple-columns-fails-with-keyerror#60377228) I learned that:

```
df.set_index(['id','iteration']).stack()#.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'metric', 0: 'value'})
```

will output different tuples, but I want to keep both values of the tuple in a row.

```
dx = df[['id', 'foo', 'bar', 'iteration']].copy()
dx['kind'] = 'regular'
dx = pd.concat([dx, df[['id', 'foo_baz', 'bar_baz', 'iteration']]], axis=0)
dx['kind'] = dx['kind'].fillna('baz')
dx.loc[dx.foo.isnull(), 'foo'] = dx.foo_baz
# now fill other NULL values
```

Would fail with a:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
instead.
```

### edit

I see that a smarter fillna:

```
dx.foo = dx.foo.fillna(dx.foo_baz)
dx.bar = dx.bar.fillna(dx.bar_baz)
dx = dx.drop(['foo_baz', 'bar_baz'], axis= 1)
```

get's the job done - but this seems really clumsy. Is there a better way?

Comment: The confusing part about your data is the logic of `metric_kind`, so if column name ends with `baz` its metric kind baz, else it's `regular`?

Comment: Yes. True story: one is a real data point, the other one a synthesized point. I want to have both in differen rows and a indicator (any 0,1 whatever will do) to separate  both classes of foo and bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to extract the relevant parts and `stack`:

```
s = df.set_index(['id', 'iteration'])

s.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(s.columns
                                     .str.extract('([^_]*_[^_]*)_?([^_]*)')
                                     .replace('', 'regular')
                                    )        

s.stack(1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
0  id  iteration        1  re_bar  re_foo
0   1          1      baz     0.4     0.4
1   1          1  regular     4.0     1.0
2   2          2      baz     0.5     0.8
3   2          2  regular     5.0     2.0
4   3          3      baz     0.6     0.9
5   3          3  regular     6.0     3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1, generalized way

Here's a method using `pd.wide_to_long` and after that using `stack` and `unstack` to swap axis.

```
# rename columns with number as prefix, so we can identify different groups
dct = {col: f'{cnt}_{col.split("_")[1]}' 
       for col, cnt in zip(df.columns, df.columns.str.count('_')) 
       if cnt > 0}
df = df.rename(columns=dct)

dfn = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                      stubnames=['1_', '2_'], 
                      i=['id', 'iteration'], 
                      j='metric_kind', 
                      suffix='[A-Za-z]+')

dfn = (
    dfn.stack()
       .unstack('metric_kind')
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'level_2':'metric_kind'})
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

dfn['metric_kind'] = dfn['metric_kind'].map({'1_': 'regular', '2_': 'baz'})
```

**Output**

```
   id  iteration metric_kind  bar  foo
0   1          1     regular  4.0  1.0
1   1          1         baz  0.4  0.4
2   2          2     regular  5.0  2.0
3   2          2         baz  0.5  0.8
4   3          3     regular  6.0  3.0
5   3          3         baz  0.6  0.9
```

---

#### Method 2, specific, not generalized

With `DataFrame.filter` and `pd.concat`:

```
d1 = df.filter(regex='id|_foo$|_bar$|iteration')
d2 = df.filter(regex='id|_baz$|iteration').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_baz', ''))

dfn = pd.concat([d1, d2]).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)
dfn['metric_kind'] = np.resize(['regular', 'baz'], len(dfn))

print(dfn)
   id  re_foo  re_bar  iteration metric_kind
0   1     1.0     4.0          1     regular
1   1     0.4     0.4          1         baz
2   2     2.0     5.0          2     regular
3   2     0.8     0.5          2         baz
4   3     3.0     6.0          3     regular
5   3     0.9     0.6          3         baz
```